# Change state one at a time for checklist

Tags: swift, swiftui

For a new checklist app in SwiftUI, I'm trying to figure out how I can change states one at a time instead of all together at once.

The checkboxes are basically UI images that I toggle once the state has changed from 'false' to 'true'.

```
  @State var checked = false
```

The checkboxes are basically an array of three that should be checked once at a time.

```
  HStack {
           ForEach(0 ..< 3) { item in
           Checkbutton(checked: self.$checked)
                        }
                     }
```

This is the code for changing the state of the checkbox.

```
Image(systemName: checked ?  "checkmark" : "plus")
```

Has anyone an idea how I can change this logic to checking the boxes once at a time?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Since SwiftUI views update based on state, that's where you need to start - separate `checked` into three variables (it can be an array). The next thing is to separate the interval. This probably is mostly dependent on what you are *really* trying to do. A `Timer` (assuming you actually have a model behind all this) might do. Or maybe logic - something you haven't (yet?) included in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have one `bool` `state` but multiple `CheckButtons`. You need an `[bool]` instead to keep track if each of the buttons is checked.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var checked = [false, false, false]

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(0 ..< 3) { index in
                Button(action: {
                    self.checked[index].toggle()
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: self.checked[index] ?  "checkmark" : "plus")
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```